# XV6 (riscv) growproc(int n) function

Tags: xv6

```
int
growproc(int n)
{
  uint sz;
  struct proc *p = myproc();

  sz = p->sz;
  if(n > 0){
    if((sz = uvmalloc(p->pagetable, sz, sz + n)) == 0) {
      return -1;
    }
  } else if(n < 0){
    sz = uvmdealloc(p->pagetable, sz, sz + n);
  }
  p->sz = sz;
  return 0;
}
```

the sz variable is passed into uvmalloc function. then in the uvmalloc function:

```
uint64
uvmalloc(pagetable_t pagetable, uint64 oldsz, uint64 newsz)
{
  char *mem;
  uint64 a;

  if(newsz < oldsz)
    return oldsz;

  oldsz = PGROUNDUP(oldsz);
  for(a = oldsz; a < newsz; a += PGSIZE){
    mem = kalloc();
    if(mem == 0){
      uvmdealloc(pagetable, a, oldsz);
      return 0;
    }
    memset(mem, 0, PGSIZE);
    if(mappages(pagetable, a, PGSIZE, (uint64)mem, PTE_W|PTE_X|PTE_R|PTE_U) != 0){
      kfree(mem);
      uvmdealloc(pagetable, a, oldsz);
      return 0;
    }
  }
  return newsz;
}
```

the sz is assigned to variable "a", the "a" then passed as second argument to "mappages" function.

my question is, the second argument for mappages is an virtual address, how comes a size variable "sz" becomes an virtual address?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I understand now.
the xv6 user process always start from virtual address 0. and initially, "sz" was assigned 0.

So, there is a hidden mapping here, size 0 mapped to address 0.
size 4096 mapping to address 4096.

Hence in xv6 user process, size is start of virtual address